# Angular ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: c#, angular

I am writing my web application using C# Web API and Angular for frontend. Currently, I have created a User controller in my backend, and also I have created a simple get request in Angular but I am getting an error: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE". I've checked if API works correctly using postman and the api is fine. The code:

Controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(int id)
{
  try
  {
    var user = await _dbContext.Users.FindAsync(id);
    if(user == null)
    {
      return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(user);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return BadRequest(ex.Message);
  }
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllUsers()
{
    try
    {
        var users = await _dbContext.Users.ToListAsync(); 
        return Ok(users);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
     }
 }
```

Users-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from 'src/app/models/user.model';
import { UsersService } from 'src/app/services/users.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users-list',
  templateUrl: './users-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users-list.component.css']
})
export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit{

  users: User[] = [];
  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) { }
    
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.usersService.getAllUsers()
    .subscribe({
      next:(users) => {
        console.log(users);
      },
      error: (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Users.service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environment/environment';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {

  baseApiUrl: string = environment.baseApiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.baseApiUrl + '/api/User');
  }
}
```

And also environment.ts file:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    baseApiUrl: 'http://localhost:7174'
}
```

I do not honestly know, what to do now. I would be glad if anyone could help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of the Network tab in devtools, with the request? Does your API see any requests incoming?

Comment: Sure: [link](https://ibb.co/5vrHf6L)

Answer (score 1):

Your backend is using the port `7174` and I guess that your frontend ist using port `4200`, it sound like a `cors` problem: [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

These two URLs have the same origin:

- https://example.com/foo.html
- https://example.com/bar.html

These URLs have different origins than the previous two URLs:

- https://example.net: Different domain
- https://www.example.com/foo.html: Different subdomain
- http://example.com/foo.html: Different scheme
- https://example.com:9000/foo.html: Different port

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved. I just forgot to type "https" instead of "http". Question is closed. Thank you for your answers